# Rendering HTML in Python when sending e-mails using import smtplib

Tags: python, html

I am trying to send an e-mail using import smtplib. And I want it to render the html and send it in an e-mail. Unfortunately it currently just sends the html code in the e-mail. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

My Code is below:

```
import smtplib
import pandas as pd

DEFAULT_EMAIL_SERVER = "x"
TO = ["y@x.com"]
FROM = "z@x.com"
SUBJECT = "TEST"
table = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsm')

body = '<html><body>' + table.to_html() + '</body></html>'
        TEXT = body


message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

            %s
            """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)


server = smtplib.SMTP(x)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`MIMEText`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText) object from `email.mime.text` to create an email that specifies it's content as HTML.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = '<html><body> <b>hello world</b> </body></html>'

my_email = MIMEText(message, "html")
my_email["From"] = "me@email.com"
my_email["To"] = "you@other.org"
my_email["Subject"] = "Hello!"

server = smtplib.SMTP(my_server)
server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, my_email.as_string())
```

This handles the formatting of the email header for you. `.as_string()` produces:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: me@email.com
To: you@other.org
Subject: Hello!

<html><body> <b>hello world</b> </body></html>
```

Comment: I can play around with it to get the formatting of the table to be in html now, but I cant get the from to and subject to work. Are you sure it should be server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, my_email.as_string()) ?

Comment: @Imccann, I did make some edits after I posted the answer. Did you see those?

Comment: ah yes got it to work now. Why do I need to add Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" to your message string:

Answer (score 1):

To send html emails using smtplib I use the following code:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

content = "<p>This is a paragraph!</p>"

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(content, subtype='html')
msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
msg['From'] = "SENDER"
msg['To'] = "RECEIVER"
with smtplib.SMTP("SERVER", 587) as smtp:
   smtp.starttls()
   smtp.login("SENDER", "PASS")
   smtp.send_message(msg)
```